# Export jena model to json file

Tags: java, json, jena

Hey i'm trying to make a web service and i'm using Jena distibution. At the moment i have created my model and its printing out in RDF/XML format. I want to get my data to a JSON file saved in my hard disk. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `org.openjena.riot.out.RDFJSONWriter` writes Talis-style RDF/JSON (i.e not JSON-LD).
2. Look for a JSON-LD writer (I think there are ones that read RDF and write JSON-LD)
3. Use SPARQL JSON Results format

Comment: Thanx im gonna try that and get back to you.

Comment: Ok i've imported org.openjena.riot.out.RDFJSONWriter but i guess i cant get the syntax right. I'm using
RDFJSONWriter jsonfile = new RDFJSONWriter(m); (m is my model).
Also how can i get this written in a file in my hard disk?

Comment: in jena-arq-2.11.0.jar this class seems to have been renamed to org.apache.jena.riot.out.RDFJSONWriter 
but the write (Writer out, Graph graph) method is [un-implemented.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-604)

Comment: I used `RDFDataMgr.write(baos, result.getGraph(), Lang.RDFJSON)` as an alternative to RDFJSONWriter when I discovered the empty body implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Now the Jena RIOT readers/writers support also the RDF/JSON serialization; then you just need to do the following:

```
org.openjena.riot.RIOT.init(); //wires RIOT readers/writers into Jena
java.io.OutputStream os = null;
// Serialize over an outputStream
os = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
model.write(os, "RDF/JSON", relativeUriBase);
```