# Reading nested RDF Triples in Jena

Tags: java, json, rdf, sparql, jena

I have a query

```
CONSTRUCT { ?highValForeignTran ?hvFTPred ?hvFTObj . }
WHERE { ?highValForeignTran vocab:accounttransactions_transactionCurrency "USD" .
?highValForeignTran vocab:accounttransactions_transactionValue ?tranValue .
?highValForeignTran vocab:accounttransactions_transactionDate ?tranDate .
?highValForeignTran ?hvFTPred ?hvFTObj .
FILTER ( ?tranValue > 10000) .
FILTER (  ?tranDate >= "2013-11-23"^^xsd:date  && ?tranDate <= "2013-11-23"^^xsd:date) .
}
```

that returns the result:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:vocab="http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:db="http://localhost:2020/resource/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:map="http://localhost:2020/resource/#">
<vocab:accounttransactions rdf:about="http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1">
<vocab:accounttransactions_id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
>1</vocab:accounttransactions_id>
<vocab:accounttransactions_transactionCurrency>USD</vocab:accounttransactions_transactionCurrency>
<vocab:accounttransactions_originAccountNumber>DB48939239</vocab:accounttransactions_originAccountNumber>
<vocab:accounttransactions_transactionType>Cr</vocab:accounttransactions_transactionType>
    <vocab:accounttransactions_transactionDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"
>2013-11-23</vocab:accounttransactions_transactionDate>
<vocab:accounttransactions_destinationAccountId rdf:resource="http://localhost:2020/resource/bankaccounts/1"/>
<vocab:accounttransactions_transactionValue rdf:datatype=
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal">12000</vocab:accounttransactions_transactionValue>
<rdfs:label>accounttransactions #1</rdfs:label>
<vocab:accounttransactions_destinationAccountNumber>47321896544567</vocab:accounttransactions_destinationAccountNumber>
</vocab:accounttransactions>
</rdf:RDF>
```

when I try to parse this using Jena however I only get one triple that represents the outer accountTransactions triple:

```
{"http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1":
 {"subject":"http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1",
  "predicate":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
  "object":"http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions"}
}
```

I have no idea why the other triples get nested inside, but I really need to be able to parse them and send them as JSON.
Here's my code:

```java
try {
Model result = qexec.execConstruct();

    JSONObject jsonShell = new JSONObject();

StmtIterator stmtIter = model.listStatements();
    while ( stmtIter.hasNext() ) {
        Statement stmt = stmtIter.nextStatement();
        JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject();
        innerJson.put("subject", stmt.getSubject().visitWith(rdfVisitor));
        innerJson.put("predicate", stmt.getPredicate().visitWith(rdfVisitor));
        innerJson.put("object", stmt.getObject().visitWith(rdfVisitor));

        jsonShell.put(String.valueOf(stmt.getSubject().visitWith(rdfVisitor)), innerJson);
    }
    System.out.println(resultJson.toString());
    }
    finally {
        qexec.close();
    }

RDFVisitor rdfVisitor = new RDFVisitor() {

    @Override
    public Object visitURI(Resource r, String uri) {
        return uri;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitLiteral(Literal l) {
        return l.getLexicalForm();
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitBlank(Resource r, AnonId id) {
        return id.getLabelString();
    }
};
```

I wonderered if `Statement.getProperty()` might do the trick, but couldn't discover a way to create a `Property` instance.

Comment: The other triples aren't "nested inside".  That's just a way RDF/XML is written.  The RDF, in Turtle looks like http://pastebin.com/yU80Kqf8 .  You're getting back good data.

Comment: I haven't used JSONObjects, but will `jsonShell.put("X", innerJson);` add a bunch of "X" elements to the JSON, or keep overwriting the previous one?  All your triples in this model have the same subject, so if you're doing `jsonShell.put(<subject-uri>,innerJson)` and if that overwrites an existing entry, you'll only end up with one.

Comment: it'd also be good to mention what JSON library you're using.  I have a project with Jena loaded, and I don't have any autocompletions for JSONObject…

Comment: Also, have a look at [Export jena model to json file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12518115/1281433), [How can I use Jena to serialize RDF in the JSON syntax?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1506/how-can-i-use-jena-to-serialize-rdf-in-the-json-syntax).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: it's  Douglas Crockford's JSON-java. You're probably right about the put overwriting. I just assumed that as the triples were nested, my code wasn't able to access them. My bad. Will verify this as soon as I get back to my project tomorrow am. Mucho gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem in your code (and the resulting JSON)

All the triples in your data (which is fine) have the same subject.  This might be easier to see in the In the more human readable Turtle format, or very explicitly in the one-triple-per-line N-Triples format.  I've included these at the end of this answer.  Since all the triples have the same subject, I suspect that what's happening is that

```
jsonShell.put(String.valueOf(stmt.getSubject().visitWith(rdfVisitor)), innerJson);
//            |-----------------------------------------------------|
//                         same every time
```

is overwriting the results of the previous iteration each time, since, as noted, the key is the *same* for each iteration.  If you add some printing statements to your loop, I expect that you'll see that you are, in fact, iterating over every triple in your model.

I can't tell you what you *ought* to use for the key there, because I'm not clear how that key will be helpful, since the subject of the triple is already encoded in the output.  It seems like you want some kind of statement ID, so maybe you could use a string representation the statement or something.

### An alternative using Jena and RDF/JSON

I'd point out that Jena can serialize a model in RDF/JSON, and that might be an easier way for you to get JSON if that's what you need.  The structure won't be the same as what you were generating of course, but that might not be a big problem.  For instance,  where `/jsonoutput.ttl` is my local copy of your data, the following code writes JSON.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class JSONObjectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read( JSONObjectTest.class.getResourceAsStream( "/jsonoutput.ttl"), null, "N3" );
        model.write( System.out, "RDF/JSON" );
    }
}
```

The resuling JSON is:

```
{ 
  "http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1" : { 
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionDate" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "2013-11-23" ,
      "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionValue" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "12000" ,
      "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_id" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "1" ,
      "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_destinationAccountNumber" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "47321896544567"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type" : [ { 
      "type" : "uri" ,
      "value" : "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionCurrency" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "USD"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "accounttransactions #1"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionType" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "Cr"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_destinationAccountId" : [ { 
      "type" : "uri" ,
      "value" : "http://localhost:2020/resource/bankaccounts/1"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_originAccountNumber" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "DB48939239"
    }
     ]
  }
}
```

### Your data in different formats

#### Data in Turtle/N3

```
@prefix db:    <http://localhost:2020/resource/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix map:   <http://localhost:2020/resource/#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vocab: <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/> .

<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1>
        a                             vocab:accounttransactions ;
        rdfs:label                    "accounttransactions #1" ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_destinationAccountId
                <http://localhost:2020/resource/bankaccounts/1> ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_destinationAccountNumber
                "47321896544567" ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_id  1 ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_originAccountNumber
                "DB48939239" ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_transactionCurrency
                "USD" ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_transactionDate
                "2013-11-23"^^xsd:date ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_transactionType
                "Cr" ;
        vocab:accounttransactions_transactionValue
                "12000"^^xsd:decimal .
```

#### Data in N-Triples

```
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_id> "1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionCurrency> "USD" .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_originAccountNumber> "DB48939239" .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionType> "Cr" .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionDate> "2013-11-23"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_destinationAccountId> <http://localhost:2020/resource/bankaccounts/1> .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_transactionValue> "12000"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal> .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "accounttransactions #1" .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions_destinationAccountNumber> "47321896544567" .
<http://localhost:2020/resource/accounttransactions/1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/accounttransactions> .
```

Comment: you're right, the **subject being the same**, and a JSON object being an associative array, the put method was overwriting the previous key (subject) entry each time. Thanks for your suggestion on RDF JSON as well. The goal was to use JSON to render a graph, so using `RDFDataMgr.write(baos, result.getGraph(), Lang.RDFJSON) ;` works as well for me.